# Can you use wget to only mirror files updated after a certain date?

Tags: unix, wget

Is it possible to mirror an FTP site (from scratch) but only obtaining files after a certain month? In other words, I want to recursively download a folder (of folders), but only for files after a certain date. Is this possible with wget?

Comment: wget doesn't have that kind of capability. it could fetch a file list from which you can use another app to parse out files meeting your specs, then pass the filename list back to wget for fetching.

Comment: If you posted that as the answer, I'd select it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm mistaken but according to the following document, it seems to me that's wget's default behavior.

[Read Http-Timestamping internals section](http://www.editcorp.com/Personal/Lars_Appel/wget/wget_5.html)